# Detect Twilio service number to prevent SMS response loop

Tags: api, sms, twilio

One of our users (probably accidentally rather than maliciously) put in Lyft's SMS service number as her phone number. As a result, our SMS text service is interacting with Lyft's SMS text service in a loop. See logs below:
[image]

I wonder if there is a way to detect this kind of machine-to-machine SMS loop and prevent it from happening. We are using Twilio API to power our SMS auto-response system and [so does Lyft](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2012/10/lyft-and-twilio.html).

Answer (score 3):

Just make a change in your app logic that would stop replying after a set number of identical messages (store a hash of every message in memcache for a few minutes or something like that.) There's no metadata to SMS messages that would allow you to conclusively identify the originator as another automated service.

Comment: Thanks pilsetnieks. As @megan-speir from Twilio mentioned, there is already a built-in rate limit for TwiML and exceeding that rate limit would result in an API error code 14107.

Answer (score 2):

You're experiencing the following: https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/errors/14107

A counter is set for each outbound [TwiML](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml) reply in a conversation (between two numbers). When the first reply occurs, the counter starts at 1. If the next reply is sent less than 15 seconds after the prior reply, then the counter goes to 2. This will continue if each reply is less than 15 seconds, until the counter surpasses 20, where Twilio will put a hold on any messages sent for 30 seconds and throw this error.

You might consider using the [Lookup API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/lookups) to try and detect service numbers which you may or may not be successful at depending on the criteria.

I would suggest that you try an example request and response on [this page](https://www.twilio.com/lookup) with the number in question and take a look at the returned parameters to decide whether or not this could have helped in this scenario.

Comment: The number lookups won't help - they would give the actual operator the number belongs to. Even if Twilio volunteers the information that they actually use the number, it won't prevent the same problem with another messaging service like Nexmo or whatever. However, the 14107 error might be helpful - but not 100% conclusive.

Comment: @pilsetnieks 14107 is definitely better than nothing. Pretty sure if it weren't rate limited, it will be used as a denial of service attack. This also makes me wonder why Neustar (aka NANPA administrator) couldn't come up with a service number registry just like what they do for short codes.